# What is the most-shared name in the Torah? In Tanach?

Tags: names, tanach, pentateuch-chumash

A [previous question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/106182/2) noted that there are three distinct individuals named Amihud mentioned in the Torah, and at least one more in Divrei Hayamim. When I noticed this phenomenon in the Torah, it made me wonder whether Amihud is the most-shared name, that is, assigned to the most distinct individuals, in the Torah.<sup>1</sup> This is basically a point of curiosity, but such a superlative status may indeed indicate homiletic value, coupled with analysis of the meaning of the name, as was provided in the [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/106392/2) to the previous Amihud question.

What name is shared by the most distinct individuals in the Torah?

What name is shared by the most distinct individuals in Tanach?

---

<sup>1. DoubleAA pointed out another name that's shared by three individuals in the Torah: Reuel, as documented in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3199/2).</sup>

Comment: Seems like a riddle like https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3195/759 (if not partial duplicate of that)

Comment: @DoubleAA I disagree that this question looks and smells like a riddle. The other one definitely does, since the way the question is stated implies (without mind-reading) that there is a specific answer that the question poser is aware of and looking for. I've stated in this question the basis for and potential value of my curiosity about the most-shared name, implying strongly (and indeed accurately) that the basis for the question is *not* that I have a known answer that I'm hiding.

Answer (score 25):

[It turns out](http://a.eliram.net/bible_records) the most common name in the Tanach is Zecharayahu:

1. A Kohen in the time of David ([Divrei Hayamim 1:15:24](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.15.24?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he))
2. A Levite in the time of David ([Divrei Hayamim 1:15:18](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.15.18?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he))
3. A gate-keeper in Ohel Moed ([Divrei Hayamim 1:26:2](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.26.2?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he))
4. Son of Yishiyah ([Divrei Hayamim 1:24:25](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.24.25?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he))
5. Father of Yado ([Divrei Hayamim 1:27:21](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.27.21?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he))
6. Father of Yachziel ([Divrei Hayamim 2:20:14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Chronicles.20.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
7. Son of Yehoshafat ([Divrei Hayamim 2:21:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Chronicles.21.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
8. A prophet in the time of Uzziah ([Divrei Hayamim 2:26:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Chronicles.26.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
9. Father of Aviah, mother of Chizkiyahu ([Divrei Hayamim 2:29:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Chronicles.29.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
10. A man from the Tribe of Reuven ([Divrei Hayamim 1:5:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Chronicles.5.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
11. Son of Yerov'am II ([Melachim 2:15:8](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Kings.15.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
12. Son of Yevarchiyahu [AKA Zechariah the Prophet] ([Isaiah 8:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.8.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
13. A descendant of Asaf ([Divrei Hayamim 2:29:13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Chronicles.29.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
14. A Kohen in the time of Yoshiyahu ([Divrei Hayamim 2:35:8](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Chronicles.35.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

[Note: if you count Zecharyah as the same name as Zecharyahu (which in the case of some individuals, it is), then there are several more individuals to add to the list]

[Note 2: the source I linked says that Zecharyahu is tied with Meshulam, however, when I looked in the concordance, it said that only 13 individuals are named Meshulam]

Comment: Well, that ought to be easy to remember.

Comment: @IsaacMoses yeah, good it's not Hatzlalpuni or Artachshashta or one of those names... :D

Comment: Phenomenal link! Thanks for sharing that.

Comment: @Eliyahu I highly agree. So many awesome Tanach facts.

Answer (score 6):

I believe (although I have no source) that Chanoch is the most common name in the Torah.

We have Chanoch:

1. Son of Kayin (Bereishit 4:17)
2. Son of Yered (Bereishit 5:18)
3. Son of Midian (Bereishit 25:4)
4. Son of Reuven (Bereishit 46:9)

Comment: Potentially Reuel is tied (Yisro, Yisro’s father, father of Nasi of Gad, son of Esav).

Comment: Does anyone hold that Yitro and his father were both called Reuel? I thought it was one or the other...

Comment: @DonielF and the father of the Nasi of Gad may have been Deuel or Druel